# Apps script convert doc to HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this function to convert a doc to HTML as a template for sending email. I've been using it for 2 years without any problem. Since yesterday I have a bug: Exception: Limit exceeded: Email body size. The basic documents have not changed.

Was there a change in the conversion that explains why the HTML size is larger?

Thanks for your help

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + id_doc + "&exportFormat=html";
    var param = {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    var doc_html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
```

If I reduce the document content, it works, but the icons in the document are not in HTML.

I did another test
If I take HTML and put it in an editor, the images are present

[image]

But not in the email sent by ailApp.sendEmail
[image]

Comment: I thought that your question might be related to this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76518920 About `Was there a change in the conversion that explains why the HTML size is larger?`, I thought that the reason for this is due to that the images are put into HTML as the data URL instead of the direct link of the image. In that thread, a workaround is also proposed. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: If this is a confirmed issue, a better place to report  this would be the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Hello Tanaike 
thank you for your reply and proposed solution, but it won't work in my case. The program manages 500 email templates with images that cannot be shared publicly. The second solution won't work in the long run, as there are a large number of emails sent every day (runtime). I'll keep looking...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful in your situation.